# Get html source of dynamic content generated through Java functions

Tags: javascript, search-engine

In the site I am working on there many Java functions that dynamically generate content when executed, the problem is this content is not visible in the source when viewing the source it show only the java function so that content is also not visible to search engines.

Is there is any way to make this content visible in source so it be visible to search engines?

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes i mean javascript

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is 'no'.  Search engines do not attempt to parse and run JS (which is necessary to recreate the output the user sees).

Comment: yes i know that search engines doesn't parse js but i am asking about method to get he source code of the geneared content

Comment: Copy it direct from the browser output if you want it.  Search engines don't (want it).